# How to predict risk scores with Cox models using lifelines package?

Tags: survival-analysis, cox-regression, survival, cox, lifelines

I have made multiple cox models with Lifelines package and I am trying to predict the risk score of each individual following information in [CoxPhFitter page](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fitters/regression/CoxPHFitter.html). `predict_hazard` is a suggested command in that page, but when I use it to predict risk scores, it runs into an error: CoxPHFitter has no attribute 'predict_hazard'. Has anyone else seen such error with `predict_hazard`?